# Python - check if variable is == to json element and print

Tags: python, json

I have a json response with thousands of student information bits. It looks like this:

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "agents": [
            {
                "href": "private url here",
                "sourcedId": "g560",
                "type": "user"
            }
        ],
        "dateLastModified": "2016-10-24T15:24:00.000Z",
        "demographics": {
            "href": "private url here",
            "sourcedId": "s557",
            "type": "demographics"
        },
        "email": "example@example.com",
        "familyName": "Smith",
        "givenName": "John",
        "identifier": "000000000",
        "metadata": {
            "ext_grade_level": "11"
        },
        "orgs": [
            {
                "href": "private URL here",
                "sourcedId": "000000000000000000000000000000",
                "type": "org"
            },
            {
                "href": "private URL Here",
                "sourcedId": "0000000000000000000000000000000000",
                "type": "org"
            },
            {
                "href": "private url here",
                "sourcedId": "000000000000000000000000000",
                "type": "org"
            }
        ],
        "role": "student",
        "sourcedId": "s557",
        "status": "active",
        "username": "000000000"
    },
    {
```

That then repeats starting with "agents": [ for the next student, approximately 2,500 times. What I'm really looking to do is the following, I have "students_data" = students_data.json().

```
json1 = students_data['users']
stu_email = input("Enter a student email address here:")

if item in json1 == stu_email:
    print(stu_email)
```

When I run that, nothing happens. It asks for an input and then just ends. No errors, no nothing. I have nothing to go off, other than it's obviously wrong. Also, if it did work, how would I then print the familyName, givenName, and identifier for the matching address?

The list nested in the dictionaries really messes me up, because the only way I know how to deal with lists is by indexing with [0] or [1] etc. however, that isn't an option in this case.

Also, I tried doing json1['email'] but I get the "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" which I assume is because I'm skipping over the list.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Here's how `if item in json1 == stu_email` works: First, Python checks if `item` is in `json1`. Whether it is or is not, the result is `True` or `False`, but none of them equals `stu_email`. You need a loop that goes through the list of students and compares `stu_email` to each student's email.

Comment: That makes much more sense, the true or false part, thanks.

Comment: P.S. Can anyone explain why my question gets down voted? I want to ask better questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json data can consist of dictionaries and lists nested within each other. Here we loop through the list `student_data['users']` to look for the first `student` with a matching email.

```
student_email = input("Enter a student email address here:")

for student in students_data['users']:
    if student['email'] == student_email:
        print('found a match')
        print(student)
        break
else:
    print('no match found')
```

Comment: I would stay on the safe side and do `if 'email' in student and student['email']==...`.

Comment: Depends on the context. If I exect every student to have a email field, I would rather raise a `KeyError` and crash the program than quietly accept corrupted json data. _Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced_

Comment: Thanks for the insight, that worked great for me. For some reason I'm having a hard time thinking through list/dictionaries.

Comment: I usually have a python repl open when I write code dealing with nested data. Then I can explore the data structure interactively and get a better understanding of the data types and the shape of the data every step of the way.